# "Android is starting..." & "Optimizing app" @ 2014 Moto X 2nd Gen

Tags: moto-x

I'm using 2014 Moto X (2nd Gen) and lately I keep getting:

`Android is starting...` & `Optimizing app` whenever I start my phone(

I tried to clear `wipe cache partition`, but that did not help towards resolution of my issue.

Comment: @onik, I have `2nd Gen` not `1st Gen`, nor do I have low space issue, _AND_ I've cleared my cache, that did not solve my issue either. My question isn't duplicate, please reopen it. Thanks!

Comment: The core question determines duplicates, not the answer or specific device details (unless they are the source of the problem).  We want to direct everyone to the same place so that any answers provided can help everyone.